# query oracle database for availability

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a lightweight sql statement that I can against an oracle database to test if the database is up, available and able to exceute sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 1
  FROM dual
```

is a common one.  You could select any constant value from `DUAL` as well.

Comment: Doing a similar thing on SQL Server, I used a string for the constant that described what was being done. Something like `select 'Server FOO Application BAR -- liveness test' from dual`. This was after looking in a log and seeing periodic selects that did not have any meaning from another application. (Of course, being SQL Server, there is no dual table, and no requirement to specify a table, so the actual code used was like `select 'blah'`.)

Comment: Note that you can still get a result from this even when the database is mounted but not open. I think (but haven't tested) that if you're doing this as a DBA then you could follow up SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL with SELECT ADDR FROM DUAL, and the latter would fail if the database is open and succeed if it is only mounted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to connect first, you could query through a link, for example, I have a set of links to an external system and I run SQL of the following form:

```
select * from global_name@myLink01.WORLD;
```

Comment: How could you run this *without* connecting (e.g. through JDBC)?

Comment: Oracle connects for you using myLink01.WORLD.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the sql statement to describe dual table, then also you will get to know it whether db is up and running.

desc dual;